# Compute $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}}dx$ via differentiation with respect to parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, improper-integrals

Integrate only using differentiation with respect to parameter:

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}}dx, \quad n \geq 0, \quad p \geq 1$$

No complex methods allowed.  This is a rather useful integral to know. By differentiation with respect to parameter, I mean writing something like

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty f(\alpha,x) dx,\ \to I'(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \partial_\alpha f(\alpha,x) dx=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^\infty f(\alpha,x) dx.$$

These integrals are mostly taken from Bulgarian math team questions.  Thanks again for the assistance and your time and help!

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $p$ and you will end up with a nice integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\ge0, p \ge1$. Let $$I_n (p) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}} dx$$.
We have
\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dp}I_n(p) & = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{1}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}} dx \\
&=-\int_0^\infty (n+1)\cdot \frac{1}{(x^2+p)^{n+2}} dx \\
& = -(n+1) I_{n+1}(p) \\
I_{n+1}(p)& = \frac{-1}{n+1}\frac{d}{dp} I_n (p)
\end{align*}
So \begin{align*}I_n(p) &= \frac{-1}{n} \frac{d}{dp}I_{n-1}(p)\\
& = \frac{-1}{n} \cdot \frac{d}{dp} \left(\frac{-1}{n-1}\frac{d}{dp}I_{n-2}\right)\\
& = \cdots = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dp^n}I_0(p)
\end{align*}

One can calculate $I_0(p)$ as follows; substitution at $(*)$ is $u = \sqrt{p}\tan \theta$. 
\begin{align*}I_0(p) & = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + p}dx\\
& \stackrel{(*)}{=} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{p \sec^2 \theta}\sqrt{p}\sec^2 \theta d\theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{p}}
\end{align*}

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dp}p^{-1/2} &= (-1)^1\frac{1}{2} p^{-3/2}\\ 
\frac{d^2}{dp^2}p^{-1/2} &= (-1)^2\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2} p^{-5/2}\\ 
&\ \vdots \\
\frac{d^n}{dp^n}p^{-1/2} &= (-1)^n\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdots \frac{(2n-1)}{2} p^{-(2n+1)/2}\\ 
& =(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdots \frac{(2n-1)}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{2}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{4}\cdots \frac{2n}{2n}\right) p^{-(2n+1)/2}\\ 
& =(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!} p^{-(2n+1)/2}\\
\end{align*}

Thus $$I_n(p) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cdot (-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!} p^{-(2n+1)/2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}p^{-(2n+1)/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $I(p)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+p}$ , and then try to express $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x^2+p)^{n+1}}$ in terms of $I^{(n)}(p)=$ $=(-1)^n\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n+1}p^n\sqrt p}\cdot\pi$.